# How to compare UTC to DateTime.now in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to check if a time submitted by the user in a datetime_field in a form is less than the current time.

My current issue is that the submitted date is that exact date in UTC, is `Mon, 13 Apr 2020 23:00:00 UTC +00:00`, however, `DateTime.now.utc` is `2020-04-14 03:14:00.694513 UTC`.

I would like to be able to compare just the dates and the times to compare them, regardless of the timezone they are in.

Comment: So the timezone is immaterial? You should normalize them to gather any sort of useful information. Please see "[ask]" and its linked pages. We'd like to see what effort you've put into this.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ in Rails one should use `Time.zone.now`, not `DateTime.now.utc` and not everything else to avoid possible issues. Here is the must-read article http://danilenko.org/2012/7/6/rails_timezones/

Comment: You say you want to compare the dates and the times but ignore the timezone. Imagine you had `2020-04-14 04:00:00 EDT` and `2020-04-14 09:00:00 UTC`. What would be the expected output?